# Why does makefile pattern rule fail with spaces in name. How do I fix it?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

For a Makefile containing...

```
File\ space.o: %.o : %.c
        echo hello
```

`make` returns

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'File.c space.c', needed by 'File space.o'.  Stop.
```

Why does it not return...

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'File space.c', needed by 'File space.o'.  Stop.
```

?

Comment: Why have source file names with spaces?

Comment: This is a minimal reproducible problem. I don't have any source files with spaces in them. I am not compiling anything.

Comment: If you're not actually compiling anything, then why do you need to fix it?

Comment: In any case, that looks like a bug in `make` to me. However, file names with spaces in them are more generally problematic to `make`, in some entirely *non*-buggy ways.  Just don't do it.

Comment: make doesn't support filenames containing spaces.  It just doesn't.  If you have to support them, you should find a different tool to manage your builds.

Comment: GNU Make doesn't have support for embedded whitespace like shells do.  The backslash-space isn't interpreted by GNU Make as a literal space. I was able to fool GNU Make into compiling a filename with spaces, but the shell then parsed the space into two separate filenames anyway.  cc    -c -o File space.o File space.c